# Prove $(y-x^2)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, but not maximal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

My guess is to use the fact that when we take the quotient,
$\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(y-x^2)$, this will become an integral domain but not a field.

I am not sure how to take the quotient, though. I am also unfamiliar with the ring of polynomials of two variables. As a set, can I write $\mathbb{R}[x,y] = \{a + bx + cy + dxy + ex^2+fy^2+...| a,b,c,d,e,f,...\in \mathbb{R}\}$?

And would it be correct if I assume that in the quotient, $y = x^2$?

If my above two guesses are correct, then I would assume that the quotient becomes $\mathbb{R}[x]$, since all the $y$ terms can be turned into $x^2$. But isn't this ring an integral domain, since there are no zero divisors, but not a field, since not every real polynomial has an inverse?

Comment: Yes, you're spot on. If you take $\sum_{i,j\geq 0} a_{ij}x^iy^j$ and set $y = x^2$, then we get $\sum_{i,j\geq 0} a_{ij} x^{2j+i}$. Every element in $\Bbb R[x]$ has this form for some $i$, $j$ and coefficients $a_{ij}$ when conveniently rewritten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the quotient is $\Bbb R[x]$. One way to see this is to consider the
homomorphism $\phi:\Bbb R[x,y]\to\Bbb R[x]$ with $\phi(f(x,y))=f(x,x^2)$.
This homomorphism is surjective, and its kernel is the ideal $(y-x^2)$,
so by the First Isomorphism Theorem for rings, $\Bbb R[x,y]/(y-x^2)\cong \Bbb R[x]$.

As $\Bbb R[x]$ is not a field, then $(y-x^2)$ is maximal. But ine can write down
lots of maximal ideals containing this ideal, for example $(x-a,y-a^2)$
for any $a\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: I'm sorry if it this is a trivial question, but just to be perfectly clear, but why is the kernel $(y-x^2)$? And what exactly does $f(x,x^2)$ mean, when the codomain has only 1 variable--I see that it is made of x and x, but why are there two spots?

Comment: Yeah I am also struggling to prove why the kernel is $(y-x^2)$

Comment: @SallyG one can show this by induction on the degree of the polynomial $f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, $x\mapsto x$, $y\mapsto x^2$ gives us a homomorphism $\Bbb R[x,y]\to\Bbb R[x]$. Show that the kernel is $(x^2-y)$ and you are done as that shows $\Bbb R[x,y]/(x^2-y)\cong \Bbb R[x]$, which  is an integral domain, but not  a field.