# Prime ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I want to show that $J:= \langle x-y^2+1 \rangle$ is a prime but not a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

My idea is that $x-y^2+1=x-(y-1)(y+1)$ and so $\langle x-y^2+1 \rangle \subsetneq \langle x, y+1 \rangle$, because $x \notin \langle x-y^2+1 \rangle$. Also $\langle x, y+1 \rangle \neq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, since $1 \notin \langle x, y+1 \rangle$. Therefore $J$ is not maximal.
To show that it is prime I have in my toolbox the Homomorphism Theorem and using the homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{C}[x,y] \to \mathbb{C}[y]$, with $\phi(f(x,y))=f(y^2-1,y)$, which is onto and has a Kernel $\ker(\phi)=\langle x-y^2+1 \rangle$, I can conclude.

Is this correct?

Comment: It seems it is.

Comment: Compare also with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3238973/prove-y-x2-is-a-prime-ideal-in-mathbbrx-y-but-not-maximal).